# Python writing results out to a file

Tags: python

I have the following script which thanks to the help of everyone is almost done as it now prints out the results to the screen. I am also looking to add one more step which will take this same screen output and dump it to a text file.

I thought this was done with `file.write()`

but dont know how to get it to write the information from results to a file. Please help, I am very new to python so I am a bit lost and trying to figure it out from the book.

This now prints out but just the last line of what is being returned by the query. Ultimately it is probably just printing one line and then overwriting it again and again so I need it to print the whole of the fetch all or results

```
import adodbapi

# Connect to the SQL DB    
conn = adodbapi.connect("Provider=SQLOLEDB; SERVER=xx.x.xx.x; Initial Catalog=master_db;User Id=user; Password=pass; ")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Execute SQL procedure things_referencing"    
curs.execute('util.things_procedure', )
results = curs.fetchall()

for row in results:
    print row

f = open('test.txt', 'w')
s = str(row)
f.write(s)
f.close()

conn.close()
```

Comment: This is an example straight from the python sql tutorials. Have you actually tried to write any data to a file before asking here?

Comment: @Lattyware: I used to keep linking that same awesome blog, until I finally needed to just sum up my own specific answer: http://writemycode.net  :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each "row" in the "results" tuple is a record tuple. How you want to format this data is up to you, but at the most basic level you can convert it to a string with `str(row)`

Now go read the python docs on how to read and write files:
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

**Update**

Referring to your new code example, you are doing the for loop and printing each row, and then you are opening a file and only writing the last value that row was assigned from your for loop. Your for loop that prints is unrelated to the write operation you then do. `row` had been assigned every value of `results`, but you only used the last assigned value, once.

What you should do is first open the file, then start your loop, writting every value of row:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in results:
        print row
        f.write("%s\n" % str(row))
```

If you use the `with` context, it will automatically close the file for you once you leave that scope. Instead of only converting to a string using `str` you can use string formatting, and add a newline character.

Comment: Ok I converted it to a str and it is print now but only the last row of the query results, actually assuming it is printing them line by line and overwriting each other....any way to prevent this?

Comment: @user1304228: Please update your question with what you have tried and what is now failing.

Comment: Updated although the f=open etc all printed out in one line those are on their own lines in my code

Comment: @user1304228: You are only printing the last `row` value after you are done looping. Open your file first, then start your for loop, and within the loop, write each row.

Comment: Thanks much! what does the "%s\n" % str(row) mean just for future reference :)

Comment: @user1304228: Google "string formatting". It lets you format a string using replacements from your arguments. Its a more efficient way of writing `str(row) + "\n"`

Comment: How do you do this for a 2D array in this case?

Comment: @8765674: Do you mean where `row` is a list of field values and you want to write them as a line??

Comment: The above method unfortunately adds likely unwanted `(` and `)`s at the beginning and end respectively of every row in file if the true database resultset  was used

Comment: @Arthur probably so. But my answer starts with saying that I leave the formatting specifics up to the author and just do a basic string conversion. The focus of the answer was how to write lines of data to a file.

Comment: @user1304228 You can also append/add a new text to the already existing file if you change the mode from "w'" to  "a"

Answer (score 1):

it is indeed done with file.write but you have to open the file first. So you would modify the for loop something like below

```
f = open('/path/to/file', 'w')
for row in results:
    f.write(row)
f.close()
```

Comment: This will crash. row is a tuple.

Comment: Yea I just tried this and it didn't print out... can you break it out from being a tuple so it writes? or is there a way to write it as a tuple